# Start a Windows Process from Program Files (x86) using Process.Start()

Tags: c#, process, filepath

I am try to start a process using Process.Start() from my C:\Program Files (x86) like this:

```
Process proc = Process.Start("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\TestFolder\\TestApp.exe");
```

This causes a Win32Exception: `The system cannot find the file specified.`

If i try to start any other process that is not in x86 folder like:

```
Process proc = Process.Start("C:\\Windows\\System32\\calc.exe");
```

it works fine.

So I assume the exception is caused by either the (x86) or the white space of "Program Files".

How can I solve this problem with the file path?

---

Solved it by doing it in the following way:

```
Process proc = Process.Start(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\TestFolder\TestApp.exe");
```

So i added the @ before the path and removed the double backslash in the path. in that way it works. if i do it with the double BS it doesnt work.

Answer (score 1):

The space in "Program Files" may be the cause. You may have to quote this path itself.

```
Process proc = Process.Start("\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\TestFolder\\TestApp.exe\"");
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to open your IDE(Visual Studio) as Administator then you can able to Open the `TestApp.exe`

Comment: That doesn't sound right.  You shouldn't need Visual Studio.  The `Process.Start()` should be executed from a standalone application (ie console).

Comment: @ppittle:Yes it's just an example the main thing is Administator